# Largest round robin ever?

Tags: history, records

First, I myself played several large (20+) *blitz* round robins, this is nothing unusual. Thus: only "long" games.

Second, oversize round robins were quite common in the good old days (maybe as a gentleman you had enough domestics to do the work?), so a [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess) might lurk there. (Didn't find it in the linked list, but you can use it to establish "34" is to beat. Because Gustav Neumann won all his 34 games. [This](https://en.chessbase.com/post/34-out-of-34-remembering-gustav-neumann) should imply it was a round robin, BTW, although I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: What is the criterium for 'largest':  the most players, or the number of rounds?

Comment: The '34' is from a club tourney, where the conditions was that every player should
play two games with every other player.  However, a player was only required to
appear in the club once a week, and then play at least one game. (Neue Berliner Schachzeitung, v. 2 (1865), p. 117) At least 22 players entered, but needless to say, many players dropped out quite quickly.

Comment: @user30536: THX for the info, I couldn't fact-check that detail first, naturally. And "most number of rounds". Ideally both are equal. (Somewhen someone will ask "most number of games"...)

Comment: As for being equal: Some older candidate RR tournaments have just five players, but each player played four or five games with every other player RR (could be argued to be a match tournament,, though). While tournaments like Palma de Mallorca, 1970 have 24 players single RR, London 1883 had 14 players, double RR, but special rules for draws, so crosstables for this show more games than expected. I suspect an answer will come from someone with access to di Felice's collection of tournament crosstables -- my own lists are very dated.

Comment: For the sheer record that would count as contender. :-)